# JaxRS path in HelloWorld example

Tags: glassfish, wildfly, restful-url

This is the first example in JEE 7 tutorials for Restful services, simply printing out "hello world" to the screen. The tutorial is configured to run in Glassfish, but I am testing it in Eclipse and Wildfly. When I start the application Wildfly, it dispalys "http://localhost:8080/hello/", the error message is:

```
Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/hello/
```

Then I run this URL: "http://localhost:8080/hello/helloworld", it works correctly. The original tutorial has this configuration for Glassfish below, so it can directly executes "http://localhost:8080/hello" to run the example.

How can I change the configuration or source code so that I can directly run "http://localhost:8080/hello" with appending the "helloworld" to it in Wildfly and Eclipse? The original tutorial doesn't even has a web.xml file to configuration. Instead it uses nbactions.xml to do the configuraiton.

```
<action>
            <actionName>profile</actionName>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <netbeans.deploy>true</netbeans.deploy>
                <netbeans.deploy.profilemode>true</netbeans.deploy.profilemode>
                <netbeans.deploy.clientUrlPart>/helloworld</netbeans.deploy.clientUrlPart>
            </properties>
        </action>
```

HelloWorldApplication.java

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /** Creates a new instance of HelloWorld */
    public HelloWorld() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of helloWorld.HelloWorld
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        return "<html lang=\"en\"><body><h1>Hello, World!!</h1></body></html>";
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of HelloWorld
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("text/html")
    public void putHtml(String content) {
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.javaeetutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>hello</name>

    <parent>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.javaeetutorial</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.5</version>
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application path is set first by the `HelloWorldApplication.java` class annotation

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
```

This means that your application will be served at the root context of your deployment, so you only need to go to http://localhost:8080/hello to get to any resource within your application.

The rest resource you have defined in `HelloWorld.java` sets its path within the application by another class annotation:

```
@Path("helloworld")
```

so JAX-RS will make this resource available with a combined path of the `@ApplicationPath` and the resource `@Path`. You can probably see for yourself that you can change the `@Path` above to be:

```
@Path("/")
```

The path to your resource will then be `context-path` + `ApplicationPath` + `Path` or, in other words your scenario would be, `your-app-name` + `nothing` + `nothing`.

When you deploy your application to GlassFish, you could even set your context path to be the root context so that you wouldn't even need to specify `hello` in the URL.